# Regular Expressions to get rows of a table

Tags: php, regex

I have a table that I am trying to parse

```
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
```

each row is similarly formatted and I want to split them apart using regular expressions. I have tried everything I can think of but it always seems to take the whole contents as the match

I've tried stuff like this

```
$pattern = ':(<tr>.*</tr>):';
 preg_match_all( $pattern , $working, &$regs2  );
```

but it always maximally takes everything in one go rather than minimally taking it row by row.

This is probably pretty basic but I just can't seen to get it.

Comment: Long story short: Don't use regex to parse HTML. Use a real XML parser.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but it didn't parse the HTML and I got nothing out of the parser which is why I resorted to regex

Comment: If you have to use regexp to parse HTML, then learn about "greedy" and "ungreedy"... and you're right, it's pretty basic

Comment: Don't. Do. It. Here's why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the regex tester I usually use, it seems to work normally. (http://regexpal.com/)
If it seems like it's too greedy, try using a ? after the * to calm it down a bit. If you're not wanting the capture the `<tr></tr>` move the () to the inside, like `<tr>(.*?)</tr>/`

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the `.*` pattern non-greedy by adding a `?`. Try `.*?` as the middle pattern  and see if the problem persists.

Really, you shouldn't use regex to parse HTML, but you did ask what was wrong, so...

Comment: Absolutely prefect. (and I really agree that I shouldn't use regex to parse HTML but other possibilities seem to fail).

Answer (score 1):

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ Use Simple HTML DOm, it will make parsing the table quite easy

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'm going to look into it!